# Spark crash when using get_json_object udf - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: json, apache-spark, hiveql, udf

I'm running a Spark 1.6.2 job on a massive data-set that has a column with an unparsed json string (which I have no control over, it can be anything). I'm running an SQL query using a `HiveContext` with the `get_json_object` UDF, but it crashes, saying:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 38
```

Is there a way to figure out what's the row that's causing this issue?

Comment: could you added what is the structure of your json and parsing logic skeleton? feel like provided information is [too less](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As I've said, the json can be anything. I'm looking for a field called `vaild`, though I don't know if it is there or not. If it is, I want the boolean value it has